# android fragments , activity

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-activity

I have set up a swipe tab using fragments in the action bar. For each view of the tab, i have a gridview with images i want to create but i can't use both an activity and fragments. So how do i create the GridView? How are fragments supposed to work with activities in such cases? This is how i've done it so far.

```
    public class SignsActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signs);

        TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
             public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }};
            //Add New Tab
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Warning").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Information").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Prohibition").setTabListener(tabListener));

    }


}
```

activity_signs.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

ProhibitionSigns.java

```
    public class ProhibitionSigns extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterPro(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            //sending the image id to full screen
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(intent);


        }


});


}
```

grid_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <GridView xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:numColumns ="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode = "columnWidth"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"

    >
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
   public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;

public Integer[] myImages = {
        R.drawable.ic_images_1, R.drawable.ic_images_2, R.drawable.warn,
        R.drawable.ic_images_6 };

public ImageAdapter (Context c){
    context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myImages.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return myImages[arg0];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);
    imageview.setImageResource(myImages[position]);
    imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70,70));

    return imageview;
}
```

}

TabPagerAdapter.java

```
    public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        //Fragement for new Tab
        //
      return new ProhibitionSigns();
    case 1:
       //.......

    }
    return null;
```

Comment: So, you want a pager with each page containing a gridview? Your activity that holds the grid view(prohibitionSigns) should be a fragment, not an activity. Then your pager can hold the fragments

Comment: Yes i want each page containing a grid view. I tried to get the pager to contain the fragments. But i'm setting up the images in the ImageAdapter which takes a context. Tried it..stuck

Comment: within a fragment you can use getActivity() to get the context

Comment: i did. Extending fragment as sha offered works. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `ProhibitionSigns` should extend `Fragment` not `Activity`

so the modified code according to fragment is

```
public class ProhibitionSigns extends Fragment {

GridView gridview;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, container, false);
        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        return view;
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterPro(getActivity()));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            //sending the image id to full screen
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", position);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);


        }


    });
}
}
```

I hope this would help you

Comment: hey e_sha..you're still extending activity here. I'm using the fragments to create each view in TabPagerAdapter.java

Comment: pls check the update @Masha it was my mistake i didn't see the edited code clearly. This is the way how you've to use your gridview as Fragment. hope this would work very fine

Comment: thanks. Tweaked it a touch and it works. Is this the same concept applied when swipping through pages?

Comment: oh. yeah it does. Thanks. Extra question: Once the images individual images are clicked on and in full view using the adapter, how can i swipe through? Used a pager to no avail

Comment: do you want to display the images in a separate viewpager to swipe through? @Masha

Comment: yeah sha that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: what is the problem you're facing right now? @Masha couldn't use this Fragment?

Comment: You've been very helpful. Thanks. The solution you provided above does work. I was asking a followup question; the problem i have now, is once i have clicked on an image, it opens in a new activity. How do i swipe through the images?